# Sql select top query

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

hello guys I have the following query:

```
   SELECT TOP(1) CommitmentLog.CommitAmt
FROM   leveldetails
       INNER JOIN CommitmentLog
               ON leveldetails.App_ID = CommitmentLog.app_id
                  AND leveldetails.Intro_ID = '999'
                  AND leveldetails.Side = 'right'
                  AND CommitmentLog.flag != '1'
                  AND CommitmentLog.CommitNo NOT IN (SELECT commit_no
                                                     FROM   binary_bal
                                                     WHERE  Intro_ID = '999'
                                                            AND Side = 'right'
                                                            AND llevel BETWEEN 1 AND 100000)
```

1st row CommitAmt value : 1500
2nd row CommitAmt value: 500
If i select the top 1 sum of CommitmentLog.CommitAmt the return value is 2000 rather than 1500
If i select the top 2 sum of CommitmentLog.CommitAmt the return value 2000 which is correct

> if i select top 1 then sum(CommitmentLog.CommitAmt)
>   it should return 1500 and
>   if i select top 2 then
>   sum(CommitmentLog.CommitAmt) it should return  1500 + 500 = 2000

Comment: "Top" filters the top N rows *after* the result set is computed.  It doesn't affect the result set itself.

Comment: please provide samples

Comment: the CommitmentLog.CommitAmt has multiple values in the table. I want to sum like top(1), top(2) etc.... if i sum top(1) then i am getting incorrect result like the query is running (top(2)

Comment: Where you sum the values.

Comment: sum(commitmentlog.commitamt)

Comment: can i sum the group by result and put in some varible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to Sum top N of your result set? Try this

```
SELECT SUM(t1.CommitAmt) from (SELECT TOP(1) CommitmentLog.CommitAmt
                                  FROM   leveldetails
                                    INNER JOIN CommitmentLog
                                      ON leveldetails.App_ID = CommitmentLog.app_id
                                      AND leveldetails.Intro_ID = '999'
                                      AND leveldetails.Side = 'right'
                                      AND CommitmentLog.flag != '1'
                                      AND CommitmentLog.CommitNo NOT IN (SELECT commit_no
                                                     FROM   binary_bal
                                                     WHERE  Intro_ID = '999'
                                                            AND Side = 'right'
                                                            AND llevel BETWEEN 1 AND 100000)
                              ) AS t1
```